# Combining to string/objects for printing

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to combine fNameTD + lNameTD together?

```
let fNameTD = $('<td>').text(employees[i].FirstName);
let lNameTD = $('<td>').text(employees[i].LastName);
```

Comment: let fullNameTd= $('<td>').text(employees[i].FirstName+' '+employees[i].LastName);

Comment: There is no java here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just concatenate the strings with `+`, similar to how I'm doing it below:

```js
let employees = [{
  firstName: 'Bill',
  lastName: 'Jones'
}, {
  firstName: 'Tom',
  lastName: 'Davis'
}];

for (let i = 0; i < employees.length; i++) {
  let fullNameTd = employees[i].firstName + ' ' + employees[i].lastName;
  console.log(fullNameTd);
}
```